# C++ question: feature similar to Obj-C protocols?

Tags: c++, objective-c, protocols, delegation

I'm used to using Objective-C protocols in my code; they're incredible for a lot of things.  However, in C++ I'm not sure how to accomplish the same thing.  Here's an example:

1. Table view, which has a function setDelegate(Protocol *delegate)
2. Delegate of class Class, but implementing the protocol 'Protocol'
3. Delegate of class Class2, also implementing 'Protocol'
4. setDelegate(objOfClass) and setDelegate(objOfClass2) are both valid

In Obj-C this is simple enough, but I can't figure out how to do it in C++.  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Basically, instead of "Protocol" think "base class with pure virtual functions", sometimes called an interface in other languages.

```
class Protocol
{
public:
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
};

class Class : public Protocol
{
public:
    void Foo() { }
};

class Class2 : public Protocol
{
public:
    void Foo() { }
};

class TableView
{
public:
    void setDelegate(Protocol* proto) { }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, except that I have one issue with that.  The different classes, i.e. Class and Class2, are themselves subclasses already.

Comment: @jfm429, that's why classes can have multiple ancestors.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that.  I can see a lot of problems with it, specifically with some particular class structures I've used in the past (I've studied single/multiple inheritance before and there are pros and cons, mostly cons) but in this situation it won't cause any problems.

Comment: Okay, I thought this was good but then I had these errors:  
http://drp.ly/1gXq1j 
And yes, the "Classin" is as it appears in the error, even though it should be "Class in".  Any ideas here?  (EDIT: Placed the text at that link because these subcomments don't seem to be able to format with line breaks...)

Comment: Oh, never mind.  I found it.  Turns out the virtual function declarations need empty function bodies.  So for something like `virtual int aDelegateFunction()` I'd need to put `virtual int aDelegateFunction() { return 0; };` in the Protocol declaration.  Works fine now!

Comment: The virtual function declarations don't need empty function bodies if you declare them as pure virtual, ie with the = 0; after them like I did in the above example.

Comment: I have another question: Let’s say Vehicle is a base class as you showed us... I only declared in a header file since this is only the protocol or the interface or the... base class in this case? Or does it require an implementation (Cpp ) file ?   ... also:

If I need to make a subclass of Vehicle and make a car that has additional properties and methods... 

 And then if I have another class that expects a Vehicle in a method or function, is it ok to declare it that way and pass it a Car subclassed  instance, knowing that it fulfills all the vehicles requirements?